# I have deployed my Django App on Microsoft Azure and Static files are not displaying, only html

Tags: django, azure, file, directory, static

I've deployed a Django app on Azure and run it, everything was working fine css, images, js. After i run Gunicorn to automate the site then Only skeleton HTML displayed, css, images and js disappeared.

this is the Erro:

/home/honest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:58: FutureWarning: `TemplateForDeviceMiddleware` is deprecated. Please remove it from your middleware settings.
  mw_instance = mw_class()
/home/honest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:58: FutureWarning: `TemplateForHostMiddleware` is deprecated. Please upgrade to the template loader.

Not Found: /static/images/sample/slider/img7.png/

May i know if i need to configure WhiteNoise for gunicorn on Azure?
Do i Need to edit my HTML templates to point to static folder in Azure?

I tried some of the solutions i saw here like setting DEBURG to True set path for static files in Settings.py but it couldn't help.

I will be glad receiving a step by step solution to this.

Thanks for the assistence.

Comment: first make sure that you are using latest version of Django, then make sure that static folder have the right structure like in [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/) . retry and give me feedback

Comment: I think there are some details missing regarding how you deployed to Azure? As a App Service or on a VM?

Comment: Thanks a lot Poula, and Klaus I deployed by creating a VM, then used local commandline to send files to my Azure IP address.